# Xcode's debugger is giving me <????> (question marks). What do I do?

Tags: multithreading, ios, xcode

This is what I see when my app crashes (for no obvious reason, sometimes on startup, sometimes much later on).

What on Earth can I do?

[image: Lots of questions marks in the Xcode debugger]

Answer (score 0):

The difference in which a line of code has been changed in both versions of the file is considered a conflict, and its indicator is a question mark. You can’t complete the pull operation until you specify how to resolve all conflicts.

Comment: So this is to do with GIT somehow..?